# How to print an OpenLayers map with its popups open using Mapfish printing module?

Tags: printing, popup, mapfish

I'm using GeoExt and Mapfish printing module for geoserver. There is a functionality, in the application I'm developing, that allows users to create popups on the map. I'd like that printing functionality allows popups to be printed with the map. Is that possible with Mapfish ?